# Is there a required safe way of storing data in QSettings in a cross platform environment?

Tags: qt, macos, registry, plist, qsettings

The mac version of my application has just started breaking its full screen and normal layouts which I save and restore using QSettings.  Even old versions of my application are now playing up for my customers.

I was just googling for something similar when I found a bug report which contained an interesting line:

```
QSettings s;
restoreState(s.value(QString::fromLocal8Bit("state")).toByteArray());
```

When saving to the computers plist's or windows registry do I have to format the data in this fromLocal8bit()?

http://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-8631
http://bugreports.qt-project.org/secure/attachment/13400/main.cpp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the data that is encoded, it's just the literal "state". The values are properly encoded and decoded if you use QByteArray or QString
.
The QString::fromLocal8Bit() part is for converting the string literal in the source file to a unicode string. It's good practice to stick to ASCII in source files, as other encodings such as UTF-8 usually don't work with all compilers, especially MSVC.

To convert literals to QString I would suggest using QLatin1String:

```
QLatin1String("state")
```

fromLocal8Bit() is strictly speaking false, as the local 8bit encoding has nothing to do with the source file encoding, where the literal comes from.
But as "state" doesn't contain any non-ascii characters, it shouldn't matter anyway.